# Screen Brightness not increassing after using "xrandr --output eDP1 1.0

Tags: 14.04, screen, brightness

Earlier I was not able to decrease screen brightness from keyboard (It was at its maximum), then I tried:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.5
```

Now screen is sufficiently dim now, but now at times if I want to increase brightness, trying (i):

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 1.0 #or 2.0 or higher
```

increases brightness but not fully (TO the level I earlier had,i.e. it doesn't increase screen brightness much), and trying (ii):

```
xbacklight -inc *percent* #increase by a given percentage
```

has no effect on screen brightness.